# How to check for paths that are too long?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to check for paths that are too long once for a whole list and only then copy/create them...

So I thought this would be good:

```
try
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
    string temp = file.FullName;
}
catch { }
```

however, no exception is thrown then.

I rather not hardcode the limits because they might change, and I might be missing a limit...

So how can I check for long paths?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/11/filesystem-paths-how-long-is-too-long.html

Comment: what you mean? are you looking for file path limit size or something else?

Comment: @TimSchmelter :) (I assume you didn't mean that as an answer.)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/35c6a451-3507-40c8-9d1c-8d4edde7c0cc

Comment: @ispiro: No, it's a comment, but it contains the answer(260chars) and even the `Path` methods like `GetTempPath` or `GetTempFileName` use that bufferlength internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the answer is given by Tim Schmelter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483319/do-backslashes-count-twice-when-creating-a-directory-but-only-once-when-getting#comment18448946_13483319) : In ILSpy it seems that `GetFullPath` uses `MaxDirectoryLength`(255) whereas `CreateDirectory` uses 248.

EDIT: It was made into an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13493378/939213).

Answer (score 10):

The `Path.GetFullPath()` method will throw a `PathTooLongException`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I don't understand - It seems that when I tried it with a slightly different path - both this and `new FileInfo(path)` threw exceptions. But in my real code - the `new FileInfo(path)` did not. (I'll have to check that out.)

Comment: @ispiro: To test it, you can write `Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\" + new String('a', 256))`

Comment: I just tried `DirectoryInfo` with a real path (-that actually exists) of over 265 and it didn't throw an exception. But when it got to `Directory.CreateDirectory(myString);` - it did. Strange.

Comment: My (partial) mistake. The path contained "\\" many times, and I guess they're counted as "\" only, so it was less than 260. But I still don't understand why the Directory creation threw a path too long exception.

Comment: `\\` is just a syntactic escape; it's a single character.