# Do backslashes count twice when creating a directory, but only once when getting full path?

Tags: c#, .net

`Path.GetFullPath(path);` works fine. But `Directory.CreateDirectory(path);` throws a `path too long` exception. Can it be that the backslashes are counted differently for the two methods?

Comment: In ILSpy it seems that `GetFullPath` uses `MaxDirectoryLength`(255) whereas `CreateDirectory` uses 248.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You can change that into an answer. It seems to be _the_ answer.

Comment: @ispiro: It's really difficult to understand the source, i'm still not sure if i've interpreted it correctly. But i've made it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) it seems that [`GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) uses the `private const MaxDirectoryLength`(255) whereas [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) uses 248.

Path.GetFullPath -> GetFullPathInternal -> NormalizePath

```
// System.IO.Path
private static readonly int MaxDirectoryLength = 255;

// ...
if (num8 - num5 > Path.MaxDirectoryLength)
{
    throw new PathTooLongException(Environment.GetResourceString("IO.PathTooLong"));
}
// ...
```

Directory.CreateDirectory -> InternalCreateDirectory (btw, NormalizePath is also called before InternalCreateDirectory)

```
// ...
string text2 = list[list.Count - 1];
list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
if (text2.Length >= 248)
{
    throw new PathTooLongException(Environment.GetResourceString("IO.PathTooLong"));
}
// ...
```

So it seems that a folder name cannot be longer than 248 chars whereas the full path (incl. each subfolder) can be longer.

Answer (score 0):

Escape characters "are counted" at **compile** time, so both methods see a single character (backslash) not two. Escape characters are "invisible" once the application is compiled, they are only visible in the source code; in other words, "\\" sequence is resolved at compile time (not runtime) and converted to a single backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You must be reaching Windows Max Path size (248 chars) , so the

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Can not create the directory.

Can you paste the Directory path?

Comment: On Windows-based platforms, paths must be less than 248 characters, and file names must be less than 260 characters. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)